# include file without swig parsing it as a template

Tags: swig-template

I would like to include a file in a swig template without swig parsing it as a swig template. Something like raw tag for files.

Using [swig-highlight](https://github.com/mrgamer/swig-highlight) I would like to get this working.

```
{% highlight 'html' %}
    {% import 'some-template-file.html' %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Problem is 'some-template-file.html' is a Jekyll template and throws errors in swig.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [raw tag](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#raw). This ignores any inside swig syntax and should, presumably, ignore any other syntax as well.

```
// inside (e.g.) index.html
{% import 'some-template-file.html' %}`

// inside some-template-file.html
{% raw %} {{ testVar }} {% endraw %}
// results in "{{ testVar }}"
```